# Unable to open generated pdf in new tab - same window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am generating pdf using jsPDF. I want to open it in a new tab. Can't figure out how to do that in the below code ?

```
<div class="row" id="content">
  <h1>  
  TEST FOR PDF GENERATION
  </h1>
  <h1 class="ml-auto">
  RIGHT CONTENT
  </h1>
</div>
<a href="javascript:genPDF()">Download PDF</a>
```

```
function genPDF()
  {
   
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  pdf.addHTML($('#content')[0], function () {
  pdf.save('Test.pdf'); //works and downloads the pdf
  pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow'); // gives error

 });

  }
```

I have included following two js in my markup-

```
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Using  pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow'); gives me error as - " TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null"

I want to open the pdf link in the SAME window but different tab. How can I achieve this ? I have tried several methods and answers provided to similar questions but have had no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried any other methods of outputting with jsPDF? If so, do they return the same error?

Comment: @iandev No method is working. Besides, I want don't want to open in a new window but in a new tab. All the solutions i have found are for opening the pdf in a new window.

Comment: @ItykaBandta I am facing the similar issue. Did you find  the solution?